# R: Search multiple rows&columns to match a list of conditions then add a new column with dichotomous outcomes

Tags: r

**Problem**: Extraordinarily large dataset with dozens of columns. How to search a list of columns and all the rows within them, and if they match conditions, create a new column that adds a dichotomous variable to the row. Normally would use Excel, but size is too large.

**Example**

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1 2 3 4
1 2 5 6
3 3 3 3
1 1 1 2
2 3 4 1
```

If any of these columns (col1-4) and any of the rows within match a list of numbers, say List: 1, 2, 3, then add a new colum (**col5**) and add 1 if it matches, 0 if not. *Repetition doesn't matter - the value returned is 1 if there is one or more occurence of any of the list conditions*.

**Potential solution idea**
For i in col1:col4, for j in row1:allrows, ifelse(row=list, col5=1, col5=0), next.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need

```
df$col5 <- (apply(df, 1, function(x) 
            !any(!table(factor(x[x %in% v1], levels=v1)))))+0L

 df
 #  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 #1    1    2    3    4    1
 #2    1    2    5    6    0
 #3    3    3    3    3    0
 #4    1    1    1    2    0
 #5    2    3    4    1    1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), col2 = c(2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L), col3 = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L), col4 = c(4L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 1L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), class = 
 "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

 v1 <- 1:3
```